# Watch document creation with MongoDB Streams

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'd like to use MongoDB streams to trigger an event each time a specific kind of data is inserted into a collection.

I've already found something roughly similar to what I'm looking for but that's only working for change streams and not insertions.

Any idea of how I can get that done?

I'm using **Mongodb** driver with **Nodejs** to get that done so my code would be something like that:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs0';
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {

const db = client.db('mydb');

// Connect using MongoClient
var filter = [{
    $match: {
        $or: [
            { $or: [{"receipt.receiver": "newdexpocket"}, {"act.account": "newdexpocket"}] }]
    }
}];

var options = { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' };
db.collection('somecollection').watch(filter, options).on('create', data => 
  {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

- Do I need to specify an `operationType` in the filter?
- I also need to get the fullDocument but obvisouly the `updateLookup` isn't the right tool, what should I use?
- What are the options I can use for the `on` event? I've used `create` but I'm not even sure it exists, does it?

Sorry about all these questions but I'm struggling to find some answers in the official doc.

SOLUTION:

Beware not to forget `fullDocument` in your request ;-)

```
function watch_insert(con, db, coll) {
  console.log(new Date() + ' watching: ' + coll);

  const insert_pipeline = [ { $match:
                    { 
                        operationType: 'insert',
                        $or: [
                            { "fullDocument.receipt.receiver": "newdexpocket" },
                            { "fullDocument.act.account": "newdexpocket" }
                        ]
                    }
                }];

  con.db(db).collection(coll).watch(insert_pipeline)
    .on('change', data => {
      console.log(data)
    });
}

async function run(uri) {
    try {
        con = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {"useNewUrlParser": true});
        watch_insert(con, 'EOS', 'action_traces');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to:

1. Specify `operationType: 'insert'`. Since you don't want to monitor updates, you don't need `updateLookup`.
2. Create a proper [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html) for your filter that includes `operationType`.
3. The aggregation pipeline filters documents that is returned by `watch()`. An example output is in the [Change Events page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#change-stream-output).

`watch()` returns a `ChangeStream`. It fires `close`, `change`, `end`, and `error` events. See [ChangeStream](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/ChangeStream.html) for more details.

Here's a full example of a changestream that listens on `insert` operation on the database `test` collection `test`. It will output documents that has the field `{a: 1}` (`'fullDocument.a': 1`) and will ignore updates, inserts of other values of `a`, or anything without the field `a`.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test?replicaSet=replset'

const insert_pipeline = [
  {$match: {operationType: 'insert', 'fullDocument.a': 1}}
]

function watch_insert(con, db, coll) {
  console.log(new Date() + ' watching: ' + coll)
  con.db(db).collection(coll).watch(insert_pipeline)
    .on('change', data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
}

async function run() {
  con = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {"useNewUrlParser": true})
  watch_insert(con, 'test', 'test')
}

run()
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer... that's working on my test DB but I have an issue on my production instance. On the production environment I get the following message: `The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets` because I'm not using a `replicaSet`... How can I get around this? My database is already almost 1TB so I cannot add redundancy on that as this would be too costly for me (especially considering that it's not that much of a big deal if the db crashes because that's a temp db in my case). Thanks in advance,

Comment: Ok, I found the answer, just restart mongo adding the `?replset=rs0` (or anything) option and then `rs.initiate()' and I'm good ;) Thanks again for your assistance,

Comment: it's not answered yet, the query still isn't working, I've updated my original post to add some extra code... Do you have an idea why it's not working?

Comment: Of course ;-) The function is called and the watcher is running but it's simply not catching up the events when an item is inserted... I can see that the listener is properly running in the logs but is there something wrong in the request itself? What's for sure is that the `on('change')` event is never triggered. Any ideas?

Comment: do you think there is something wrong with the request itself?

Comment: or perhaps I should open up a new question for that particular question and consider this one solved (as the initial question is solved in a way - I know how to watch for inserts ;-) It's just that my particular insert doesn't seem to be working :p).

Comment: Success... I was missing `fullDocument` in the xpath of each of my requests! Problem solved, many thanks again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

## Solution for macOS users, using homebrew

> You can adapt it to your variant by looking for a solution to some points

1. Stop mongo service: `brew services stop mongodb-community`
2. Edit `/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf`
3. Add this line:

```
    replication:
       replSetName: "rs0"
```

4. Save file and open mongo shell: `mongo`
5. Run this command: `rs.initiate()`
6. Exit from mongo shell: `exit`
7. start mongo services: `brew services start mongodb-community`
8. In your mongo client configuration, add this option: `replicaSet=rs0`

And  "`The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets because I'm not using a replicaSet`" error will go away!