# NodeJS & MongoDB: Send emails and dashboard notifications to multiple users on document insertion

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io, nestjs

I am developing an application using the MEAN stack.
To be specific, I am using NestJS, Mongoose and Angular.
But the architecture explanation can be in plain NodeJS/ExpressJS and MongoDB.

I need some guidance on how I would architect a system with the below requirements.

I have a use case where, when a document is inserted in **collection1**, I need to do the below.

1. Send emails to a set of users (can be thousands) in **collection2** and **collection3**
2. Send push notification to a set of users (can be thousands) in **collection2** and **collection3**. The push notifications for a user have a maximum limit so after a number is exceeded very old ones need to be deleted.

**What I know**

- I once played around with a Redis-based queue for Node which is Kue, I see now there is Bull; This can be used to queue these processes of sending emails and notifications.
- I once used SocketIO for sending messages from the back-end to the front-end
- I see MongoDB has change streams (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/changeStreams/); I am not sure if they also emit when a new record in added in a collection. I will check this ([Watch document creation with MongoDB Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618218/watch-document-creation-with-mongodb-streams))
- I have worked with Nodemailer for sending emails.

Now  I need  guidance or second thoughts in terms of the logic of piecing it all together.
And also I would like to know if these tools I have mentioned above are the way to go for this requirement.

For example, I can do the following steps.

1. When data is inserted in **collection1**, react (MongoDB change streams) to insertion by;
2. Query all matching user documents in **collection2** and **collection3**.
3. Loop through each user in the sets(**collection2** and **collection3**) - I am not sure if the looping is efficient
4. For each user; schedule a process for sending an email using e.g. Bull and Nodemailer
5. For each user; schedule a message/notification emission by the opened socket using socketIO.

I have fear of not utilizing some tools or technologies for the application.
I am looking to go with the most efficient approach and use the most efficient tools from the start.
I am looking at building a very big platform.

Any ideas, thoughts, links to read and suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be easier if we just focus on the requirements vs the flow right now.

From your post you want to do

send email ( possibly thousands ) and also, a push notification, and an emit to a socket server ( possibly socket.io )

Now, from a tools perspective, using say

nodemailer (for sending emails)
Socket.io (for emitting to socket server)
Parse, (fill in the blank for push service)

Should all work fine and its better to think of them as just seperate pieces of the application not as one depending on the other because each service hands off the request to a seperate server, for example

Nodemailer sends the request to an SMTP server (mailgun, sendgrid, you own smtp)
Socket.io send the request to your socket server, to send to all the channels
Push notifications sends the request to your push server to send a push notifications.

With that being said, in your application after an insert is done you want to

Send emails
Send to socket
Send push notification

( thats a lot of notifications! :D)

So, after the insert is done to the DB you will probably need to query the DB to get the emails, this may also contain the channels to emit (socket.io) and the push channel as well.

Once the query is done you will construct the email object for nodemail, nodemail does support bulk email sending, so you should look into that for configuring the SMTP and pools etc. But, if the emails are all going to be the same, you can simply construct the to OR BCC with all the users. This would then just be one send with multiple users. Not need to loop over and send individually, however if its customized you may need to loop and send each one as they are dynamic ( full disclosure, you may be able to do this with a single JSON file but I cant say for sure on that one)

Once the request is sent off to the SMTP server, that process is no longer your concern ( from the node side that is, the request was sent so it will process on that server )

Next you would send an emit to the socket server, this would contain the 'channel' you wish to emit to, so any user connected to it will get that update. Again, once this is done it no longer your concern as the socket server got the request and will perform any needed logic and 'emit' to the channel ( rooms for socket.io )

Finally, we will post to the push notification server ( I'll use parse as an example but it should be the same for most )

You push server should have API key to allow you to post to the api and send a push notification using specific channels. You will just construct the correct API call to your push server, and once again its no longer your concern as the push server will take care of sending the notifications.

Each one of the actions are not tied to the other so you could perform them in any order really.

Just some final thoughts on it, you probably will not get it 'right' at the start I think its more important to get things working, refactor as you go, be agile. As your build the app efficiencies will present themselves, new tool will come out, you will look back at the first route compared to the last and be like WTF was I thinking. What is important, is that you don't over complicate things. If you find a new tool that better fits your needs in the future you can just swap it out because they don't depend on one an other.

Comment: Hi @proxim0, thanks a lot for such a detailed answer it is really eye opening and gave me some ideas, thank you!